# Labels for Django select form field

Tags: python, django, forms, select, label

I am using ModelForms to make forms for a website, but I want more control of what text is displayed in the Select box.

An example model could look like this

```
class Test(models.Model)
    ID = IntegerField()
    Label = CharacterField()
    recipient = ForeignKey(Person)
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
```

So, my problem is, that when I make a modelForm of this model, the foreign key fields are made into select fields, that has the primary key of the object in the underlying value, and the text displayed is the text from the objects `__unicode__()` method. In this case, only the product ID is displayed (this is a serial code number, which makes no sense to the user). I would like to be able to make a custom label like "[serial], [product name]".

I can't seem to find any pointers on the official Django documentation, so i wondered if anyone would help? :)

Comment: Can't you change `__unicode__` method of the model to show whats expected?

Comment: That would be the obvious solution, but the unicode method is used alot throughout the website, where it is important for it to only show the serial. So that's is not an option, I'm afraid

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [Django docs regarding the ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/). Quote:

> The `__unicode__` method of the model will be called to generate string
>   representations of the objects for use in the field's choices; to
>   provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and
>   override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object,
>   and should return a string suitable for representing it. For example:
>
> ```
> class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
>     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
>         return "My Object #%i" % obj.id
> ```

Comment: That looks like something, that might work. I'll check it out

Comment: Nice and clean. I like.